# how to extend base.html from outside of the package?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

i need to extend base.html in my other packages.

My app structure

```
-flask_blog
|-- app_bone
|     |-- __init__.py
|     |-- blog
|     |     |-- __init__.py
|     |     |-- routes.py
|     |     |-- templates
|     |     |     |-- blog
|     |     |     |     |-- blog.html
|-- templates
|     |-- base.html
-run.py
```

app_bone/blog/route.py

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint

blog = Blueprint('blog', __name__, template_folder='templates')


@blog.route('/')
def blog_list():
    return render_template('blog/blog.html')
```

app_bone/templates/blog/blog.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1> blog </h1>
{% endblock %}
```

i found this error when i run the flask

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: base.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flask documentation your project layout should look like this
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/tutorial/layout/
then you can reach `{% extends 'base.html' %}` with this your base.html file.